# How to reply to a message using SMTP and IMAP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, imap

This is the code I have at the moment. Does anyone know how to work off of it in order to reply to a message instead, of just sending a new one to the same user? I've looked at many different Stack Overflow pages, and I've tried to implement the same things in my code. However, it just sends the message to the user, and I could not understand the explanations on the other pages.

```
import smtplib
import vacci_bot
from modules import *
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import email

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

USER = os.environ.get("ADRESS")
PASS = os.environ.get("PASSWORD")

def send_mail(email, postal_code):
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as smpt:
        initialize(smpt)
        smpt.login(USER, PASS)

        msg = vacci_bot.scrape(postal_code)
        send_message, to_adress = message(email, msg, postal_code)
        print(send_message, to_adress, postal_code)
        smpt.sendmail(USER, to_adress, send_message)

def initialize(smpt):
    smpt.ehlo()
    smpt.starttls()
    smpt.ehlo()

def message(email, text, postal_code):
    body = MIMEText(text) 
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message["to"] = email
    message['from'] = USER
    message['subject'] = f'Vaccines near {postal_code}'
    message.add_header('reply-to', email)
    message.attach(body)

    return message.as_string(), [message["to"]]
```

Comment: In addition ik im not running these functions at all and that's because im using it as a module/package for my other main script

Comment: This looks like Python code. Can you please edit the tags to add python and/or python-3.x tags? I would edit tags but the suggested edit queue is full, so I can't.

Comment: You need the message-id header, of the mail you're replying to, and put that in an In-Reply-To header at a minimum.

Comment: @Max can you show me a snippet of what you mean so the message["Message-id"] would be the id of the mail im replying to and the Reply-To header would equal to message id?

Comment: @Max I tried what you told me to try but the problem now is its sending a message to me by replying to itself and its not even sending a new message but quoting the old message its replying to.

Comment: Do you have a gmail account? Use it to send a message to yourself, then send yourself a reply, and if you want send a reply to the reply. Now look at the Message-ID, In-Reply-To and/or References fields in the header of the three messages. Do you see how each reply refers to the preceding message? That's what you have to achieve.

Comment: I do see that however my goal is to just send a reply to the original message at first however the thing will will reply to itself and quote itself. I want to make this clear, is it the Uid i should be using in the in reply to headers or is it a full on id i need to be using.

Comment: It is the “Message-Id” header from the headers of the message, which has nothing to do with the IMAP UID or the IMAP sequence number.  You have to download the headers parse them, and read the Message-Id header, which looks like `Message-ID: <blah.872378344.shz@example.com>` then stick the contents of that in your In-Reply-To and References: headers.  As @arnt says, look at the headers of some messages that are threaded in your email account and see how they are arranged.